# What is the closure of $A = \{x| 1<\|x\|<3\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$ and why am I wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, terminology, definition

> Given
>
> $A = \{x| 1<\|x\|<3\} \cup \{(0,0)\}$
>
> Find $\bar A$

My hunch is $\overline A = \{x| 1 \leq x \leq 3\} \cup \{0,0\}$, but my friend says I am wrong, the closure of $A$ must be $\overline A = \{x| 1 \leq x \leq 3\}$

I am curious as to why I am wrong:

my textbook (Charles Pugh real mathematic analysis) says that $\overline A$ is the set of all limit of $A$. A limit is defined as a point for which there is a sequence in $A$ converging to it. $\{0,0\}$ is a limit of $A$ because the constant sequence $(z_n) = (0,0)$ converges to it.

my friend's textbook (Munkres Topology) says that $\overline A$ is union of $A$ and the set of all limit *points* of $A$. $\{0,0\}$ is not a limit point, because there is a neighborhood that does not contain points in set $A$ other than $\{0,0\}$

What is the closure and who is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is true that $(0,0)$ is not a limit point of $A$, it is contained in $A$, hence must be in the closure. This doesn't contradict the definition in Munkres because he defines the closure to be the union of $A$ and the set of limit points of $A$.

By the way, I'm assuming that $A$ is being viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard Euclidean topology.

Comment: Ugh so the closure is the set of all limits and not the set of all limit points. I am very frustrated with the definition given in Pugh

Comment: Both definitions are fine, since every $a\in A$ is the limit of the constant sequence $s_n=a$.

Comment: A limit point of a set is such that there exists a sequence, **none of whose terms are the limit itself**, which converges to that point. This definition is not useful here, but is the correct one and is used in higher mathematics as well. According to me the closure of a set is the smallest closed set _containing it_. In short, if there are any limit points _outside the set_, include them in the closure. With that definition, $(0,0)$ should be in the closure of $A$, and you can tell your friend that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Can you provide a reference text to that definition regarding sequential definition of limit point? Because in either text Pugh or Munkres the limit point is defined as a point $a$ such that all balls around $a$ contains some point $b \in \mathcal{A}$

Comment: Our teacher in 8th class told us this definition was from Baby Rudin. Suddenly I'm not so sure, but I've used this definition for the last $7$ odd years and faced no qualms. Having said that, it's a very negligible difference in definition,so it should not matter.

Comment: To me, the "best" definition of the closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing the original set. That is, $\overline A = \cap C$ where the intersection is taken over all closed sets $C$ with $A\subseteq C$.